# nested modules in .gitignore

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gitignore

I have a simple spring boot & angular app. I want to push it all to one repository but I have no idea how to ignore node_modules or how to use these two ,gitignore files on one push? Here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: Just add `/node_modules` in .gitignore file in `frontend` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the .gitignore file that is in the root (where the git repository was initialized) of your application and add
`src/main/frontend/node_modules/`
You can use multiple .gitignore files, but by default only the root one is used and if you just need to exclude the node_modules then the aforementioned solution will work.

Comment: Actually I tried with src/main/frontend/node_modules (without slash on the tail) and spent some time on this.. Thank you!